# maven-jetty-plugin question

Tags: maven-2, jetty, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

I need to start jetty before module tests. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jetty-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>Hello world!</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.26</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-webapp-for-module-tests</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-webapp-for-module-tests</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <daemon>true</daemon>
                    <stopPort>8181</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>stop-webapp</stopKey>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Everything works, but maven-antrun-plugin (or any other plugin before test-compile phase) begins to run two times. I tried to use run-war, run-exploaded or deploy-war goals. Result is the same.

Maven output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - jetty-test:jetty-test:war:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: test-compile}]
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     **[echo] Hello world!**
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Preparing jetty:run
[WARNING] Removing: run from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: test-compile}]
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     **[echo] Hello world!**
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] [jetty:run {execution: start-webapp-for-module-tests}]
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Unnamed - jetty-test:jetty-test:war:1.0
[INFO] Webapp source directory = /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes directory /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/target/classes does not exist
2010-12-24 16:50:17.254:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] Context path = /jetty-test
[INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
[INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/main/webapp
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.26 ...
2010-12-24 16:50:17.316:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2010-12-24 16:50:17.416:INFO::No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] [jetty:stop {execution: stop-webapp-for-module-tests}]
2010-12-24 16:50:17.603:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Stopping server 0
2010-12-24 16:50:17.637:INFO::Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp[jetty-test] in [/home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/target/jetty-test-1.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources[/home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in[25 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/chardex/projects/untitled/jetty-test/target/jetty-test-1.0.war
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
...
```

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html), for `mvn jetty:run`,

> This goal is used in-situ on a Maven
>   project without first requiring that
>   the project is assembled into a war,
>   saving time during the development
>   cycle. The plugin forks a parallel
>   lifecycle to ensure that the "compile"
>   phase has been completed before
>   invoking Jetty. This means that you do
>   not need to explicity execute a "mvn
>   compile" first. It also means that a
>   "mvn clean jetty:run" will ensure that
>   a full fresh compile is done before
>   invoking Jetty.

This explains the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a separate goal which does the same thing but does not fork the lifecycle. It's impossible not to execute the compile phase and all other phases when the plugin is run as a step in the build lifecycle, so everything is run twice. Bug created: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1365. Bug moved as a duplicate to https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1405. They said they couldn't reproduce the problem and need a specific test case. Not sure when I can get to this, but if someone has a simple war project using the maven-jetty-plugin which demonstrates the issue, can they please upload it to the JIRA ticket.