# Maven: Multiple plugins invoking multiple lifecycles

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, dbunit, hbm2ddl, maven-jetty-plugin

I've been using maven for quite some time (years), so it's surprising to me that I've never come across this issue before, or at least have some way of dealing with it...

I am trying to invoke the following plugin/goals (in the specified order):

1. sql-maven-plugin:execute
2. hibernate3:hbm2ddl
3. dbunit:operation
4. jetty:run

In a nutshell, I'm creating a database, generating a schema, inserting data, and then starting up a webapp.  However, both the hbm2ddl and jetty:run goals invoke (fork) lifecycle phases of their own, which causes some of the other bound plugin goals to run multuple times.

This is obviously not what I want.  Is there any way to workaround this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: can you post relevant parts of your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a few Stack Overflow issues related to this (jetty:run goal in particular), with some related bugs:

- [maven-jetty-plugin question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526773/maven-jetty-plugin-question)
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1365
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342643